# Error: attribute 'package' in <manifest> tag is not a valid Android package name

Tags: android, android-package-managers, aapt2

I am trying to write an android app, which used to build once upon a time. Now, everytime I build, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
C:\Users\Jay\AndroidStudioProjects\DndTools-App\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:2: AAPT: 
error: attribute 'package' in <manifest> tag is not a valid Android package name: 'dndtools'.
```

I originally started off with an android-kotlin tutorial as the base, since I wanted to familiarize myself with kotlin and android, if that might be relevant. Also, "Merged Manifest" has `package = dndtools` instead of `com.dndtools.android.dndtools` listed, also not sure if relevant.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.dndtools.android.dndtools">

  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" //dndtools
...
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
def androidSupportVersion = '28.0.0'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "dndtools"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
...
```

I have searched the internet, and others who had this error usually had an underscore at the start or end of their applicationId (which is not the case here), so I am really at a loss

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Change `applicationId "dndtools"` to `applicationId "com.dndtools.android.dndtools"`.

`applicationId` in your build.gradle file is what is used as the real package, that's why you can see it in the merged manfiest as well. Update it to match the one you have in your Android Manfiest and it should work fine.

As for why it's an invalid package - it needs to have at least one dot in it to be installable on Android.

Comment: I havefigured it out myself at this point, but this is the correct answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

My problem was with uncorrect naming of the package id. I put something like `com.example.3d`. You can't start with the number like `3d`.

Comment: thanks, so stupid by android

Answer (score 4):

In my Case, I have **updated** the Android studio to **version 3.5.3**, and while project setup, by mistake I have added  **applicationIdSuffix = kotlin_version**, so this is what causing the problem.

So simply removing this line helped me to fix this issue.

Comment: I too had a similar issue. I had to remove the applicationIdSuffix  and VersionNameSuffix from apps's build.gradle.

Answer (score 3):

A full Java-language-style package name for the Android app. The name may contain uppercase or lowercase letters ('A' through 'Z'), numbers, and underscores ('_'). However, individual package name parts may only start with letters

Answer (score 2):

in my case, i build app use default config

```
compileSdkVersion 30

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.webview.app"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    applicationIdSuffix kotlin_version
}
```

when i add productFlavors

```
  flavorDimensions "default"
  productFlavors {
    test01{
        dimension "default"
        applicationIdSuffix ".test"
        versionNameSuffix "-test00"
    }

    test01{
        dimension "default"
        applicationIdSuffix ".test"
        versionNameSuffix "-test01"
    }

    test01{
        dimension "default"
        applicationIdSuffix ".test"
        versionNameSuffix "-test02"
    }
}
```

then i'm runing my app,  i got this message

```
tag is not a valid Android package name: 'com.webview.app.1.4.21.jb'
```

i think the problem shoud be number and point(.) can not be package name, so i delete code

```
applicationIdSuffix kotlin_version
```

it's work for me, because kotlin_version value it's `ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.21"`, when my appid contain number and point(.) it cannot working. in android the appid(pacakege name) should be like this 'come.domain.project' it is reverse domain name.